# Privileged Helper Tool within a Swift project

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

I've created an Xcode project using Swift and a privileged Helper tool using Objective-C. The helper tool works fine within a project which has also been created in Objective-C but it doesn't seem to work within a project created with Swift.

The service itself is being installed. I can see the helper binary within the `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools` directory and it's permissions seem to be okay (as well as the user: `root`). Removing the helper by using `launchctl` results in re-installing the tool when my project runs (that works as expected) but I can't call any method of the helper tool.

There is neither any exception being thrown nor does any other error occur (at least there seem to be no error as the Console shows nothing as well).

Does anybody know whether this might be an issue with Swift? Because running the same helper tool within another project (written in Objective-C) works well.

Comment: Do you install helper tool using SMJobBless? Have you looked Console.app logs?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SMJobBless and that seems to work (OS X asks for credentials when installing the tool and its binary lies within the helper folder). I've checked the Console.app but it show's absolutely nothing.

Comment: Sorry for question but have you checked return value and error value of SMJobBless? Also before call SMJobBless in Swift application try to remove job using SMJobRemove

Comment: Yes. I perform checks on every `Authorization` function whether it returns `errAuthorizationSuccess`. They do.

Comment: But what if SMJobBless return's error. For example if code signing failure reason.

Comment: Also if it's a new application check bundle name of application and value SMAuthorizedClients which in Info.plist of helper tool.

Comment: I have an `assert` after requesting the privileges which doesn't fail. Though I had to go through a lot of pain with that authorization stuff I know that I would receive an error if authorization fails or both (app and helper) aren't signed properly. As I mentioned the installation seems (!) to work as the helper binary is being copied into the helper folder and owned by `root` user. It is also being listed within the services registered with `launchd`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66112/discussion-between-toohtik-and-thegoonie).

Answer (score 1):

I could figure out what the problem was. The helper tool has a `main.m` wich contains a `main()` method. I just forgot to fill it with code that creates an instance of my helper class and trigger its listener:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Helper.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        Helper *helper = [[Helper alloc] init];
        [helper run];
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

This code causes the `Helper` instance to run in an infinite loop waiting for incoming connections (from `Helper.h`):

```
- (void)run
{
    [_listener resume];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
}
```

`_listener` is an instance of `NSXPCListener`.